# Slick cannot load the image?

Tags: java, image, embedded-resource, slick2d

So I'm following [thenewboston](http://youtube.com/thenewboston)'s tutorials on Slick 2D. I'm loading the Image exactly as he said:

```
private org.newdawn.slick.Image playNow;
...
public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
...
playNow = new org.newdawn.slick.Image("res/playNow.png");
```

This is my Eclipse project tree:

[image: tree]

This is the output it gives me:

```
Tue Jul 03 09:31:53 PDT 2012 INFO:Slick Build #274
Tue Jul 03 09:31:53 PDT 2012 INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.8.5
Tue Jul 03 09:31:53 PDT 2012 INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 1366 x 768 x 32 @60Hz
Tue Jul 03 09:31:53 PDT 2012 INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 640 x 360 x 0 @0Hz
Tue Jul 03 09:31:53 PDT 2012 INFO:Starting display 640x360
Tue Jul 03 09:31:53 PDT 2012 INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true
Tue Jul 03 09:31:53 PDT 2012 INFO:Controllers not available
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: res/playNow.png
at org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(ResourceLoader.java:69)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:169)
at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:196)
at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:170)
at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:158)
at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:136)
at net.sourceforge.whowantsakookie.hamblaster.Menu.init(Menu.java:21)
at net.sourceforge.whowantsakookie.hamblaster.Game.initStatesList(Game.java:20)
at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:164)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:390)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314)
at net.sourceforge.whowantsakookie.hamblaster.Game.main(Game.java:31)
```

The tutorial is located [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqKwYtk29QM)

I am doing this exactly as the tutorial said, and it works for him in the video. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The code snippet does not show the package, which is relevant with no `/` prefix in the `String`.

Comment: That's the way I've seen it. In `org.newdawn.slick.ResourceLoader`, it gets it as an InputStream.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The resource would need to be at `org/newdawn/slick/res/playNow.png` for that `String` to work from that class.  If it is actually at `res/playNow.png` use `"/res/playNow.png`" (not the prefix `/`) as the `String`.

Comment: It still does the same thing, even with the forward slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your problem is that the "res" folder is in the same folder as the "src" file is in!

move your "res" folder containing all of your pictures INTO the "src/net.sourceforge.whowant/" folder/package in your program.

In your program you will load it by using

```
playNow = new org.newdawn.slick.Image("res/playNow.png");
```

Hope this helps! :)